# Wrong result in react-native when I use flexDirection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I use the below code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop:30,flexDirection:'row',}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',width:50,height:50}}><Text>1</Text></View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'green',width:50,height:50}}><Text>2</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and the result is:

[image: result]

I think the correct result should be:

[image: expected result]

why is the result not what I expect it to be?

Comment: you have an `rtl` support for your app ?

Comment: I didn't use, I used different code, maybe one of them support rtl, how can i find it?

Comment: checkout androidManifest file `android:supportsRtl="true"`

Comment: I search supportsRtl in my program, but cant find anything

Comment: try searching `allowRTL ` on your whole app

Comment: Nothing found  .

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli : I find "rtl-detect" in file package-lock.json

Comment: then it might be used somewhere in your code  ... try to search for `rtl-detect`

Comment: Just find in file "package-lock.json"

Comment: the only two cases I know that could cause that are: **rtl support** and **flexDirection: ''row-reverse'**

Comment: If I use your code I correctly obtain the red square 1 on the left and the green square 2 on the right. Probably you have a RTL (or flexDirection) issue here... You can check it writing a couple of words in a <Text> component and see how it is rendered...

Answer (score 0):

use `flex` instead of height and width like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop:30,flexDirection:'row',}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red',flex:.5}}><Text>1</Text></View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'green',flex:.5}><Text>2</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

you can set flex according to yourself. this is just an example...

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, it's because of location that set in Genymotion, I use below code in App.js and solve the problem

```
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native'
I18nManager.forceRTL(false)
```